# Can we approximate a matrix power series like NSum does?

Tags: matrix, summation, series-expansion, approximation, estimation

Essentially, the following does not work, and I'm wondering if it can be made to:

`NSum[ MatrixPower[B,n], {n,0,∞}]`

(Here `B` is a large, square, primitive matrix.)

I.e., if eigenvalues, inverses and determinants are too taxing to compute, is there a way to approximate this series, in the manner of NSum?

Comment: Maybe `NDSolveValue[{y'[t] == B . y[t] . y[t], y[0] == IdentityMatrix[4]},   y[1], {t, 0, 1}]`?

Comment: Multiplying two matrices of size $5000 \times 5000$ takes about $3.2$ seconds on my machine, inverting one such matrix takes about $4.5$ seconds. (I mean matrices with floating point, machine precision entries, and packed.) The difference is small. What is the situation that you have in mind where inversion is much more expensive?